# Updating a record using LINQ Context?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

i am trying to update a user table with a single value update, but i can't figure  out what i'm doing wrong. this is what i have:

```
public static void ApplyROB(string  ROBread, string userName)
        {
            using (SERTEntities ctx = CommonSERT.GetSERTContext())
            {
                    // +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
                    // Audit of the transfer
                datUser trUser = new datUserRole();
                trUser.ROB = ROBread;
                trUser.AccountName = userName;
                // Persist update to DB
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```

am i way off? nothing happens when i click on the update.
how do i say, where username = username? did i do it right?

basically in need a simple:

```
update datUser set ROB = "Y" where AccountName= "myusername"
```

it's turning out to be a bit more complicated in LINQ using Context

please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not adding your new entity to the context, thus when you save, the context is unaware of any changes. You need something like...

```
ctx.datUserRoles.Add(datUserRole)
```

To do an update, you need to retreive an entity from the context, make changes to it, then save... so:

```
var entity=ctx.datUserRoles.SingleOrDefault(dur=>dur.AccountName==someUserName);
if(entity!=null)
{
    entity.someProp=someVal;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    throw new UnexpectedOperationException(); //or however you want to fail
}
```

Comment: now i'm getting errors. i must be on the right path (before nothing was happening at all) but how do i know if this is doing an update or an insert?

Answer (score 2):

If you need an update. Maybe something like this:

```
public static void ApplyROB(string  ROBread, string userName)
{
    using (SERTEntities ctx = CommonSERT.GetSERTContext())
    {
        var trUser= ctx.datUserRole.Where(a=>a.AccountName==userName)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
        if(trUser!=null)
        {
            trUser.ROB = ROBread;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are sure that you will always have something to update you can use `First()`. Then you do not need to check if the `trUser` is `null`

Comment: thank you! the a=>a - is that a variable i need to substitute, or do i just leave it as a?

Comment: It is a linq expression. So yes you need it

Answer (score 1):

spender is correct in a sense, incorrect in another: you want to update an existing record.

For that you'll need to select the record first, for instance:

```
var user = 
    (from u in ctx.datUserRoles 
    where u.AccountName == "accountname"
    select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where `accountname` is a valid thing of the same type - that doesn't matter, since you can select it how you want, you can touch that up to meet your criteria. Then once you have the item do the stuff:

```
if (user != null) {
    user.ROB = ROBread;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yay for "splender"! Read carefully... it's actually "spender"!

Comment: @spender I'm legitimately sorry. Don't mean to offend.